# Tomcat só lê Log4J.properties quando reiniciado

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

Até pouco tempo atrás eu fazia alterações no arquivo ***log4j.properties*** (*ex: alterar o level da classe TesteMB*) e bastava fazer o redeploy da aplicação. Agora, as alterações só surtem efeito quando eu reinicio o Tomcat.

O que será que houve?

***Log4j.properties***

```log
log4j.rootCategory = WARN, console
log4j.category.console = WARN
log4j.appender.console = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %p %c:%L (%M) %m%n 

log4j.logger.br.com.nilson.control.TesteMB=INFO
```

- Tomcat7.0.47
- Log4j 1.2.16

Comment: É um problema difícil de diagnosticar a distância, mas faça o seguinte teste: (1) inicie o tomcat e a aplicação, (2) gere alguns logs, (3) pare a aplicação (stop) mantendo o tomcat rodando e, finalmente, (4) veja se o arquivo de log pode ser apagado (deletado do disco). Minha suspeita é que pode ter alguma referência de log estática que não está sendo finalizada.

Comment: É, bem possível que seja um leak do classloader. O log4j.properties é usualmente carregado pelo classloader.

Comment: Concordo com o @elias . O Log4j do Tomcat deve estar conflitando com o log4j da sua aplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente, consegui resolver meu problema usando um inicializador do Log4J

```
public class Log4jConfigLoader extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        try {
            URL url = Loader.getResource("log4j.properties");
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not start log4.properties monitor");
        }
    }
}
```

WEB.INF

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>log4j-init</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>br.com.uniondata.servlet.Log4jConfigLoader</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 1):

É possivel fazer da seguinte maneira:

Para fazer o Log4j recarregar seu arquivo de configuração automaticamente quando ele sofre mudanças, você pode fazer isso com o método configureAndWatch. Mas o procedimento de inicialização default não usa configureAndWatch (se você apenas colocar o arquivo .properties no classpath).Dessa forma você pode escrever pouco de código para o Log4j para fazer isso. A solução que encontrei foi a implementação de um Tomcat LifecycleListener.

```
import org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleEvent;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class Log4JInitializer implements LifecycleListener
{
    private String propertiesFile;

    public String getPropertiesFile()
    {
        return this.propertiesFile;
    }

    public void setPropertiesFile(String propertiesFile)
    {
        this.propertiesFile = propertiesFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent event)
    {
        if (Lifecycle.BEFORE_START_EVENT.equals(event.getType()))
            initializeLog4j();
    }

    private void initializeLog4j()
    {
        //Log4j monitora o arquivo para mudanças
        PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(propertiesFile);

        // shutdown log4j (e na thread monitor) no shutdown
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                LogManager.shutdown();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT

monitore o "BEFORE_START_EVENT", e quando isso acontecer (o que é uma vez por inicialização do Tomcat) Eu inicializo Log4j utilizando o método configureAndWatch. Também não se esqueça de configurar um Shutdown Hook limpeza da thread Log4j criada para consultar o arquivo de configuração para mudanças (eu também poderia ter escolhido para ouvir o "AFTER_STOP_EVENT" do Tomcat no lugar).

Este pacote esta em um jar. Colocá-lo no classpath Tomcat, e agora você pode configurá-lo em sua serverl.xml Tomcat.

assim:

```
<Server>
   <Listener className="Log4JInitializer" propertiesFile="/path/to/log4j.properties"/>
</Server>
```

Comment: Onde configuro este listener? Tentei incluí-lo no WEB.INF mas parece não estar sendo acionado.

Comment: Editei com as configurações do server.xml

Comment: Acho que esta não é a melhor maneira, pois pelo visto eu terei um log4j.properties para todas os app do meu servidor, não?

Comment: O log é de aplicação. Não de servidor. Então sim, você teria que configurar o log4J para cada applicação normalmente.

Comment: Entendi. então o properties vai crescer de acordo com a quantidade de apps.

Comment: isso mesmo. para cada aplicação voce pode fazer um listener especializado